# How do I show $f_0 \sim f_1 \Rightarrow f_0 + g \sim f_1 + g$

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider two smoothly homotopic maps $f_1,f_2:M \to S^1$ from a compact smooth $n$-manifold $M$ to the unit circle.

How do I show

$$f_0 \sim f_1 \Rightarrow f_0 + g \sim f_1 + g$$

for all $g:M \to S^1$

I am thinking since $f_0 \sim f_1$, than there exists a smooth map $F:[0,1]\times M \to S^1$ such that

$$F[0,p]=f_0(p) \text{ and } F[1,p]=f_1(p)$$

we can than add $g$ to both sides

$$F[0,p]+g=f_0(p)+g \text{ and } F[1,p]+g=f_1(p)+g$$

than I want to show $F+g$ is smooth? But I don't know is $g$ smooth or not.

Comment: how to define $+$? ($f+g(x)= f(x) g(x)$?)

Comment: Isn't $+$ is just addition in the usual sense? Since $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$, so addition is the group operation here?

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of $\mathbb S^1 = \{e^{i\theta}: \theta\in \mathbb R\}$ so I write the multiplicative notation. Now the concept is clear.

Comment: If $g$ is not smooth there is no way that your map is smooth.

Comment: Than is a map from compact smooth manifold to a smooth manifold guarantee to be smooth? I can't remember there is such theorem.

Comment: That is not true for sure.

Comment: There's another way round if you are to use this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176399/continuous-maps-between-compact-manifolds-are-homotopic-to-smooth-ones

Comment: I don't know is that proposition gonna help or not. What I have in mind at the moment is that since $S^1 \cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ than can I write $f_0(p)+g = f_0(x)$ for some $x$ in $M$? Than $F[0,x]=f_0(x)=f_0(p)+g$, than we done.

Comment: What's that $p$?

Comment: $p$ is a point in $M$.

Comment: You cannot find that in general.